# Volley connection get all data in one time with use (Where) Conditional Sentence

Tags: php, android, mysql

I use Google Maps to display specific location.
The data of location get from my database and it's already available into database.
Every field in my database has own location as Latitude and Longitude.

For example

Student 1 - Seating Number - Semester - Latitude   - Longitude

Student 1 -       3        -   2      - 33.8523341 - 151.2106085

like that..

The problem is Volley connection get  all students location data from databases at once time .This is error, I should only get the data of chosen student (I use Conditional Sentence (Where) into url of Volley and php file to get specific data.But I don't Know Why still it's not work ).

As you can see picture below that I have two students in the database and their location points appear at same time when I order one student.

[image]

And this picture from database as you can see I have to student now :

[image]

If any one know the solution please help me I need to display different locations according to the data in the database for each student.

```
public class GetMapLaction extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    GoogleMap gMap;
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    private final LatLng mDefaultLocation = new LatLng(-33.8523341, 151.2106085);
     FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;
    private static final int DEFAULT_ZOOM = 6;
    private CameraPosition mCameraPosition;
    private Location mLastKnownLocation;
    LatLng latLng;
    String title;
    private boolean mLocationPermissionGranted;
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
    private static final String KEY_CAMERA_POSITION = "camera_position";
    public static final String st_ids= "st_id";
    public static final String TITLE = "nama";
    public static final String LAT = "Latitude";
    public static final String LNG = "Longitude";
    private static final String TAG = GetMapLaction.class.getSimpleName();
    TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mLastKnownLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_LOCATION);
            mCameraPosition = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_CAMERA_POSITION);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.get_map_lcation);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        final String st_id= i.getStringExtra("st_id");
        textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView) ;
        textView.setText(textView.getText() + st_id);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        if (gMap != null) {
            outState.putParcelable(KEY_CAMERA_POSITION, gMap.getCameraPosition());
            outState.putParcelable(KEY_LOCATION, mLastKnownLocation);
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        gMap = map;

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(GetMapLaction.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
  permission!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
            getMarkers();

        } else {
            requestStoragePermissionn();
        }
    }


    private void requestStoragePermissionn() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Permission needed")
                    .setMessage("This permission is needed because of this and that")
                    .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(GetMapLaction.this,
                                    new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                          dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
                    .create().show();

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)  {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                getMarkers();
                gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                gMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                gMap.setMinZoomPreference(7);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission GRANTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission DENIED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    }

    private void addMarker(LatLng latlng, final String title) {
        markerOptions.position(latlng);
      markerOptions.title(title);
        gMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        gMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), marker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }


    private void getMarkers() {
        final String url ="http://000000000/stedant/map.php?st_id=" + st_id;
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.e("Response: ", response.toString());
                    try {
                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        String getObject = jObj.getString("data");
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(getObject);
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            //  title = jsonObject.getString(TITLE);
                            latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LAT)), Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LNG)));
                            addMarker(latLng, title);
                         gMap.animateCamera(zoomingLocation(latLng));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(GetMapLaction.this, "This is my Toast message!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(GetMapLaction.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
    private CameraUpdate zoomingLocation(LatLng latLng) {
       return CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 7);
    }


    private void getDeviceLocation() {

        try {
            if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
                Task<Location> locationResult = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                locationResult.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Set the map's camera position to the current location of the device.
                            mLastKnownLocation = task.getResult();
                            if (mLastKnownLocation != null) {
                                gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                        new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),
                                                mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Current location is null. Using defaults.");
                            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: %s", task.getException());
                            gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                                    .newLatLngZoom(mDefaultLocation, DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                            gMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e)  {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    private void updateLocationUI() {
        if (gMap == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
                gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                gMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            } else {
                gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
                gMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                mLastKnownLocation = null;
             //  getLocationPermission();
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e)  {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","test","","student");

$st_id= strip_tags(trim($_GET["st_id"]));
$sql="SELECT * FROM Student where st_id= $st_id";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$data=array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$data["data"][]=$row;

}
    //header('Content-Type:Application/json');

    echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Comment: Hi ! can you give precision about what you mean by showing location ? What I understood so far, is that Volley retrieve well your 2 students but maps doesnt zoom where you want. I think you should have a closer look in the for loop inside 'onResponse()'                                               Your for loop executes it self very fast and gmap.animateCamera() can't keep the pace and will only display your LAST student.

Comment: The camera does not go to the location of the chosen student, it goes to the location or marker  of  first student in the database

Comment: (Your for loop executes it self very fast and gmap.animateCamera() can't keep the pace and will only display your LAST student) if that is problem how i can solve it sorry  I'm new developer I don't know everything

Comment: Ok, can you tell me what is the exact purpose of your app ? I can help you by providing a code in the answer section.

Comment: The problem now code of volley get  all students location data  from databases at once time .This is error, I  should only get the data of chosen student (I use Conditional Sentence (Where) into url of Volley and php file to get specific data.But I dont Know it's not work ).

Comment: I updated my question to make it more clear

Comment: @Andy still don't work get all records at once time

Comment: I looked for the cause of problem a lot time , but I don't  have  found a solution for it until yet

Comment: If your problem is so that more than one marker is shown in map, you can clear map before choosing new point.

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin I show more than one marker in map and I use (Conditional Sentence (Where)) Like that, I'm supposed to see one sign . And also not just that problem main problem is that the camera does not go to the point I choose according to id of student.

Comment: You should use  mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom("location",12f)) for zoom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you should declare this at the top of your activity :

```
private String st_id = "";
```

Then in `onCreate()`, get your string from the intent like you did.

```
st_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("st_id");
```

And when calling method getMarkers(), make sure your `st_id` String is not empty, because php will send you the entire data base.
here :

```
final String url ="......../stedant/map.php?st_id=" + st_id;
```

tell me if that solved your pb;

Comment: Still not true, my brother . JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0); \This line actually returns to me with one result, but it also does not appear the other result when I choose it, it is fixed on only one result

Comment: Yes, but you said you actually want to display one student at a time am I right ?  If so, just use getMarker(int st_id) whenever you need it,with an iterator probably.

Comment: yes that right but each student with different location not all student have same location /example now I have different location about you . If user select me user will be can see my location . And if he  select you user will be can see your location like that .

Comment: Now with your code me and you have a data into database but if user select my profile he can see my location but if select your profile user will see my location also with you ...that problem We are both fixed on one location

Comment: How do you allow the user to select the student ? Using buttons or recyclerView ?

Comment: I am going through three steps until this stage First steps - the user selects the student through (recyclerView )---The second step - the data is passed to other activity  (detail Activtiy) I pass data to this activity by use (onItemClick(int position) ) on (recyclerView ) then from (detail Activtiy) I pass data to map activity by use intent.putExtra and here into map activity is a problem as you can see above code)

Comment: Hi brother, can you  look here if you have some tiem. Maybe you have  answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61542209/how-can-intent-or-pass-data-through-on-click-image-in-slider-layout-android