# How can intent or pass data through on click image in (slider Layout) android

Tags: android

I am a new application developer I try  intent or pass data through on click image in (slider Layout) from first activity to the second activity. I try to intent (name) to second activity.

I now have a different set of images now, each one having its own name.if user clicking on the first image will intent or pass data of first image only.Also if user clicking on the five image will intent data of five image only.Like that what I want to do.

Please if anyone knows the answer help me.

```
import com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderLayout;
import com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderView;

 public class SlidShowMain extends AppCompatActivity {
    SliderLayout sliderLayout;
    private List<SlidShowListData> list_dataList;
    private JsonArrayRequest request;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private static final String HI ="http://=========/S.php";
TextView textView5;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.slide_show_new);

        sliderLayout  = (SliderLayout) findViewById(R.id.imageSlider);
        sliderLayout.setIndicatorAnimation(SliderLayout.Animations.WORM);

        list_dataList=new ArrayList<>();
        sliderLayout.setScrollTimeInSec(1);
textView5 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        SliderView sliderView = new SliderView(this);
        setSliderViews();


    }

    private void setSliderViews() {
        request = new JsonArrayRequest(HI, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        SlidShowListData listData = new    SlidShowListData listData = new SlidShowListData(jsonObject.getString("imageurl"),jsonObject.getString("name"),jsonObject.getString("id"));
                       String name = jsonObject.getString("id");
                       textView5.append(name + ", "  +"\n\n");
                        list_dataList.add(listData);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                setupdata(list_dataList);


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });


        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(request);

    }

    private void setupdata(List<SlidShowListData> list_dataList) {

        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {

            final SlidShowListData ld = list_dataList.get(i);
            SliderView view = new SliderView(getBaseContext());
            view.setImageUrl(ld.getImageurl());
            view.setImageUrl(ld.getname());
            view.setImageScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            final int finalI = i;
            sliderLayout.addSliderView(view);
            view.setOnSliderClickListener(new SliderView.OnSliderClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSliderClick(SliderView sliderView) {
                    Toast.makeText(SlidShowMain.this, "" + (sliderLayout.getCurrentPagePosition() + 1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class SlidShowListData {
    private String imageurl;
    private String name;
    private String id;
    public SlidShowListData(String imageurl,String name,String id) {
        this.imageurl = imageurl;
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getImageurl() {
        return imageurl;
    }
    public String getname() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

```
 implementation 'com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
```

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","=====","=====","show");

$sql="SELECT * FROM slhow";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$data=array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$data[]=$row;

}

    header('Content-Type:Application/json');

    echo json_encode($data);


?>
```

I have tried to write it as follows:

```
holder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(context,HomeActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id",======.=======()); // here problem
                context.startActivity(intent);
```

I don't know what I should  write or how on the second line into (====) to send an ID.must send the Id of image that user just clicks, not all ids of images

Anyone know  solution , please help me

Comment: No comments \ Nobody can solve this problem?

Comment: Wouldn't creating `new Intent(secondActivity)` inside `public void onSliderClick(SliderView sliderView)` work?

Comment: I have updated my question, please check it

Comment: Hi, do you want to send data from one activity to another one? Have you tried intent?

Comment: yes I wnat that ..  I get data from database like image and id so I wnat when user click any Image the id of that Image send to other activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code for sending data from FirstActivity:

```
 val intent = Intent(this@FirstActivity, SecondActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("imagename", imageid)
            startActivity(intent)
```

And this for delivering date in SecondActivity:

```
var imageid = intent.getStringExtra("imagename")
```

Comment: When I try your code in field of imageid intent.putExtra("imagename", imageid) come error like that (Cannot resolve symbol 'imageid'

Comment: Yes, imageid is id of your image. I gave you an example. @Marwan

Comment: I know I try to write id but same problem

Comment: In your code, in which variable you save id of image? Put that id there @Marwan

Comment: I apologize, but I did not understand very well. Please see the full code here //https://www.gulf-up.com/3z8rusb2q05y
Until the idea becomes clear well

Comment: It seems that with public String getImageurl() { return imageurl; } you want to get url of image. After you get URL put it in imageid place @Marwan

Comment: If you are say I have to do  like that :     public String id;      intent.putExtra("id",id); I do but still no data pass into SlidShowMain activity \\ If your idea is different, please update your answer so that the answer is clear

Comment: Check in logcat that you are getting url correctly or not? @Marwan

Comment: I get data from database and also I can see image  into SliderLayout and Id I can see it in textview into  first activity but data not pass to other activity ..// places If you can open https://www.gulf-up.com/3z8rusb2q05y that file to understand problem

Comment: Use this code where you are getting the id, can you say what is id? @Marwan

Comment: yes brother // I see all ID that into my table by this code ==== String name = jsonObject.getString("id");
                       textView5.append(name + ", "  +"\n\n");

Comment: Hi brother . I get solution it like that == intent.putExtra("id",ld.getid());

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me