# Editext values getting cleared while moving from one activity to another activity

Tags: android, android-edittext, sharedpreferences

I have three edittext and one button in Main Activity. 
If I click button in MainActivity it will move to Activity2. And, if click button in Activity2 it will move back to Main activity. The MainActivity edittext values getting cleared if I go back MainActivity.
I need to save the edittext values. Is there any way to do this except Shared Preferences.

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button bt1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);

        final EditText et1 = findViewById(R.id.et1);
        final EditText et2 = findViewById(R.id.et2);
        final EditText et3 = findViewById(R.id.et3);


        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Activity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Activity2

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2);

        Button bt2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2);

        bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });



    }
}
```

Comment: In Activity2 call `finish()` instead starting new MainActivity

Comment: Move data to different activities

Comment: See my answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61542209/how-can-intent-or-pass-data-through-on-click-image-in-slider-layout-android

Comment: finish() is working thanks. I have one more question, it is possible to add edittext1 and edittext2 values when switching from activity2 to main activity?

Comment: Can anyone please answer fo this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/61995729/10212894